# Send array from 1 view controller to 2 other separate view controllers

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an array in one view controller that I want to send to two other view controllers - i am doing it via a `prepareForSegue:`

```
var userId = ""

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let FollowersUsersViewController = segue.destination as! FollowersUsersViewController
    FollowersUsersViewController.followersUserId = userId

    let FollowingUsersViewController = segue.destination as! FollowingUsersViewController
    FollowingUsersViewController.followingUserId = userId
}
```

For the other 2 view controllers I am calling the array like so:

View controller 1:

```
var followersUserId = String() 
let followersProfileId = followersUserId
```

View controller 2:

```
var followingUserId = String() 
let followingProfileId = followingUserId
```

It seems to work when i send it to one of the view controllers (and comment out the other) but then only one of the buttons work when i run the app. When I do it for both view controllers (as above) i get a `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` error - how can it work for both?

Appreciate any help :)

Comment: Do you have one button that segues to `FollowersUsersViewController` and another button that segues to `FollowingUsersViewController`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is crashing because you are trying to cast wrong view controller. Thats is in a single iteration the `segue.destination` either `FollowersUsersViewController` or `FollowingUsersViewController`.

You have conditionally cast it before use.
Try this code

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let controller = segue.destination as? FollowersUsersViewController {
        controller.followingUserId = userId
    } else if let controller = segue.destination as? FollowingUsersViewController {
        controller.followingUserId = userId
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do to improve this code is to make both VC's conform to a protocol that enforces this variable's presence:

```
protocol UserIdController {
    var userId: UUID { get set }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let viewController = segue.destination as? UserIdController {
            viewController.userId = userId
    }
}
```

It would be less descriptive but much more elegant and swift-like.